# Cannot resolve method startactivity()

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to the android development and having a bit of a problem changing activities. I am trying to change activities from within a method but I am getting the error cannot resolve method startActivity and on the parameter end the error Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent (...)'. I found a question here with the same sort of problem and tried to implement their replies into my program but no joy.

Here is the code:

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.Blogin) {
        EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFusername);
        String str = a.getText().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
        i.putExtra("Username", str);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    if (v.getId() == R.id.Bsignup) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Complete code:

```
package in.chaitu.example.loginandregister;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.Blogin) {
            EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFusername);
            String str = a.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
            i.putExtra("Username", str);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        if (v.getId() == R.id.Bsignup) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the name of your activity class ?

Comment: you can also use the CONTEXT.startActivity(i); ,Here CONTEXT is your context of the acctivity

Comment: is this onButtonClick called in your xml onClick?

Comment: try MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);

Comment: try:   v.getContext().startActivity(i);

Comment: my activity class is MainActivity.java

Comment: @ Priya try answer posted below

Comment: It looks like your activity isn't being recognised as a context - are AppCompatActivity or the Imports and @Override also showing errors>

Comment: remove extends AppCompatActivity and try extends Activity

Comment: @user2025187 don't make bad suggestions based on my comment. That's not fixing a problem, it's fixing a symptom. Are you going to tell him/her to go and change anywhere they use the library?

Comment: Well priya has been back to respond but is ignoring my comments just as they also ignored T.Dimitrov. It looks like *another* racist voting ring only responding to other Indians.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i= new Intent(this, Display.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button Blogin,Bsignup;
EditText a;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFusername);
Blogin = (Button) findviewById(R.id.Blogin);
Bsignup = (Button) findviewById(R.id.BBsignuplogin);

setonclicklisteners();

}

public void setonclicklisteners()
{
Blogin.setOnClickListener(this);
Bsignup.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.Blogin:  
         String str = a.getText().toString();
         Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
         i.putExtra("Username", str);
         startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.Bsignup:
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
        startActivity(i);
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: How does rebinding the listener and changing from if to switch, help at all with resolving a method?

Comment: by implementing OnClickListener

Comment: Ok, but how is it related to the question then?

Comment: @NickCardoso my question title is "you can try like this" given another solution

Comment: If it is a question, then it belongs as a comment. Answers are for solutions, not checking things. @priya what code are you on about. I haven't written any code.

Comment: if you want solution, then you have to check @NickCardoso

Comment: That's precisely why questions allow comments - "Have you tried making the activity implement onClickListener?". You also still have not said how you believe this could be related to a method in Activity not resolving